# Unable to restore backup of Whatsapp (switching phones only)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, file-transfer, google-backup

I'm following the tips, that are on a WhatsApp website, on what to do when upgrading phone.

I'm moving from Samsung S7 to Asus Zenfone 8. Asus provides app for that, but WhatsApp is notably missing the chats. The way it's now it contains only contacts.

Old phone app had no backup whatsoever, so created one on Google drive for gmail account, which is main account on both phones. It took 12 hrs, but it's done.

Unfortunately new phone app says there's no backup available on that account.

I verified it's the same account. Have both old and new phones, SIM is in new one.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Investigated a bit and apparently Whatsapp DOESN'T create backup on Google Drive. Every way I look at it, Drive reports 0% of 15GB used. WhatsApp reports backup of 4,1 GB has been created and it's even incrementing it when I choose backup manually.
What the heck?

Comment: Check if there's a backup for WhatsApp on https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/backups.

Comment: Regarding your update - WhatsApp back up is **not** included in drive space. It is independent and you don't pay for it. I have 17 GB of Whatsapp backup with Google Drive of 15 GB. See this https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/about-google-drive-backups/?lang=en

Comment: @beeshyams I agree with you, but just to make sure and also let OP know where to check backups on Google Drive since it's kind of hidden for unaware users :)

Answer (score 1):

That account was set up 7 years ago and on that phone (S7) 4 years ago. In a different country. With different phone number.
It was working just fine until now, and only just now I realized that the phone numbers didn't match.

After changing phone numbers on the old phone WhatsApp, the new phone WhatsApp found the backup and successfully restored it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Whatsapp backup setting and add an email for backup. You can set backup frequency to daily, weekly or monthly. And remember the email address. You can easily backup if you are switching mobile in this case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).